# Swagger,JWT and SPRING

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt, swagger

I have added JWT authentication to my spring project. The code can be run on Postman. Now I am trying to add Swagger to it. I have been able to add the Authorization in the swagger. [image]

. I think because of it, I have this field in all my requests.
[image]

But this adds authentication to all the paths. How to fix it?   The code is given below.

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {

    @Bean
    public Docket api() {

        Parameter authHeader = new ParameterBuilder()
                .parameterType("header")
                .name("Authorization")
                .modelRef(new ModelRef("string"))
                .build();

        List<SecurityScheme> schemeList = new ArrayList<>();
        schemeList.add(new ApiKey(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "JWT", "header"));
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .produces(Collections.singleton("application/json"))
                .consumes(Collections.singleton("application/json"))
                .ignoredParameterTypes(Authentication.class)
                .securitySchemes(schemeList)
                .useDefaultResponseMessages(false)
                .select()
                .apis(Predicates.not(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("org.springframework.boot")))
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build()
                .globalOperationParameters(Collections.singletonList(authHeader));
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add WebMvcConfiguration. Configure the application not to add authentication to a specific link (the link to the swagger).

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.anonymous().and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/actuator/**").permitAll().antMatchers("/v2/api-docs")
                .permitAll().antMatchers("/swagger-ui/").permitAll().antMatchers("/swagger-ui.html").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/**").authenticated();

    }
}
```

My swagger configuration goes like this

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).select().apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.any()).build();
    }

}
```